# Design Cloud Firestore to get objects with objects inside themselves

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to design Cloud Firestore database to retrieve objects which have objects inside themselves? I have one object which has 5 other objects inside and I would like to retrieve it from this database. If it is possible, how can I do it?

```
data class Article(var objectId: String? = null,
               var objectType: Int? = null,
               var typeOfScaling: Int? = null,
               var title: String? = null,
               var header: Header? = null,
               var source: Source? = null,
               var listOfRelatedArticlesIds: List<String>? = null,
               var listOfParagraphs: List<Paragraph>? = null,
               var listOfPhotos: List<Photo>? = null,
               var tour: Tour? = null): Serializable

data class Header(var title: String? = null,
                var content: List<Pair<String, String>>? = null): Serializable

data class Source(var srcDescription: String? = null,
              var photoId: String? = "Z1_0",
              var url: String? = null,
              var page: String? = null): Serializable

...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something in code?

Comment: First I'm trying to transfer an object to the database, but I don't know how I should design it

Comment: Yup. It is possible to have nested classes, which are then stored as maps in Firestore. If you're having problems with this, edit your question to show the [minimum, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, It works